# Comparing a variable and a predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to check if a variable, say X, is a predicate of the form add(*). How do I check if this is true? X == add(*) does not work, neither does X is add(_). How can I achieve this comparison?

Comment: It would be easier if you provided some context.

Comment: You're doing a bit of guessing without looking up the documentation for what `==/2` and `is/2` are r eally for. Is there any constraint on what arguments `add` my have?This is unclear in your question If it's strictly one argument, you could use `X = add(_)`. If it's arbitrary, you could use the `=..` operator, `X =.. [add|_]`. If you want at least one argument, then `X =.. [add, _|_]`.

Comment: The add in my context takes a single list as a parameter. That's why I tried `X == add( _ )`. However, this does not work. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The general, generic way to do so is:

```
Specific = add(_), ..., subsumes_term(add(_Any), Specific).
```

Often, people will optimize this to:

```
Specific = add(_), ..., nonvar(Specific), Specific = add(_).
```

But in the general case, you will need `subsumes_term/2`